# Solr: How do I join on a subquery?

Tags: solr

I've found documentation on [joins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser) and documentation on [subqueries](https://lucidworks.com/post/nested-queries-in-solr/), but I'm not sure how to combine them.

I want to search for something by `id` (this is a variable that's passed in).  That result will have a `sectionpath`.  I then want to find all the documents that *start* with that `sectionpath`.  Can I do this in one query?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
sectionpath:_query_:"{!fl=sectionpath}id:<variable>"*
```

I know this doesn't work, but here's the intent of this: give me results where `sectionpath` starts with (that's what the * is for) the `sectionpath` of a document that has the id of `<variable>`.  I know this is far from working, but I'm not sure how to get close to my intent.

I've also tried something like this:

```
{!join from=sectionpath to=sectionpath}_query_:"{!fl=sectionfullpath}id:<variable>"
```

But this seems to be returning close to everything.  It doesn't seem to be restricting by sectionpath.

Comment: so, you did you try something already? seriously man, you have 18k reputation, i guess you knew, how to ask questions properly. In general - yes you could do this in one query

Comment: @Mysterion I updated my question, thanks a lot for the comment.  You're right that I should have shown my attempt.  I just knew it was so far off I was a little embarrassed about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple phases to achieve desired result but in short; yes it's possible to use a field's value in a single query.

We are going to use `[subquery]`[*](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/transforming-result-documents.html#subquery) transformer and after that `{!prefix}`[*](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/other-parsers.html#prefix-query-parser) query parser. Also, we will use a [field value as input](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/transforming-result-documents.html#document-field-as-an-input-for-subquery-parameters) in subquery.

First, query the documents whose values you will use in subquery:

```
q=id:123
```

or if you will only use id to filter main documents you can use filter query;

```
q=*:*
fq=id:123
```

Specify subquery and choose the fields you want to retrieve for main documents:

```
fl=id,section_path,childpaths:[subquery]
```

Provide query for subquery, also using main document field (in raw query params):

```
childpaths.q={!term f=section_path v=$row.section_path}
```

Here we are using `!term` query parser to indicate the field we want to search on. Also by using `v` we are referencing an auto variable named `$row` to get the main document and its `section_path` value.

Remember, this will construct the query like `section_path:xyz` but we want to get documents whose `section_path` values *start with* main records'. Basically we want to construct a query like `section_path:xy*`. Luckily we have a `!prefix` query parser for that. So change the `childpaths.q` to;

```
childpaths.q={!prefix f=name_en v=$row.name_en}
```

Specify child document fields you want to retrieve (also in raw query params):

```
childpaths.fl=id,section_path
```

You can also limit child documents to get only *5* rows like so;

```
childpaths.rows=5
```

And you can modify other query parameters too, just like a regular query.

Fire the request and voila!

Here is the full query:

```
q=*:*&fq=id:123&fl=id,section_path,childpaths:[subquery]&childpaths.q={!prefix f=name_en v=$row.name_en}&childpaths.fl=id,section_path
```